# Move help text link close to Shiny label

Tags: r, shiny

I wish to have an actionLink popup a web page with help text.

My issue is in positioning the actionLink adjacent to the `numericInputIcon` label.

Ideally, it should like similar to this:
[image]

Code

```
library("shiny")
library("bslib")
library("shinyjs") 
library("shinyWidgets")

form_field_width <- "160px"
per_month <- "/mth"

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, 
                   # bootswatch = "flatly",
                   "font-scale" = 1.0), 
  
  div(class = "container-fluid",
      
      hr(),

      h1(id = "title_heading", "Some Fields"),
      
      div(class = "row",
          div(class="col-3", 
              numericInputIcon(
                inputId = "ggg",
                label = "ggg",
                value = 0,
                min = 0,
                max = 100,
                width = form_field_width,
                icon = list(NULL, per_month)
              ),
          ),
          
          div(class="col-3",
              actionLink("ggg_help", "Help")
          ),
          
          div(class="col-5",
              numericInputIcon(
                inputId = "hhh",
                label = "hhh",
                value = 0,
                min = 0,
                max = 100,
                width = form_field_width,
                icon = list(NULL, per_month)
              )
          )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ggg_help, {

    runjs("let params = `scrollbars=no,resizable=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=300,height=500,left=100,top=100`; 
          open('https://google.com/', 'test', params);")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: moditying UIs in shiny is a pain most of the time. Hope someone attempts and resolves. I am already struggling with some other similar question to align items in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `numericInputIcon` to below piece.

```
numericInputIcon(
                inputId = "ggg",
                label = HTML(paste0("ggg ", actionLink("ggg_help", "Help"))),
                value = 0,
                min = 0,
                max = 100,
                width = form_field_width,
                icon = list(NULL, per_month)
              )
```

Comment: Very clean and elegant answer. Thank-you.